# Inputting a string into dynamically allocated memory of char in c++

Tags: c++, string, dynamic, char

Is this correct or is there a better way to do this.
*Visual Studio gives an error saying '**strcpy() is depreciated**'.*

```
using namespace std;
char* ptr;
ptr=(char *)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
cout << "Input the equation." << endl;
string eqn;
getline(cin, eqn);
ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, top + eqn.size()+1);
strcpy(ptr, eqn.c_str());
```

P.S. I want to ptr to be the exact size of the input equation.

Comment: Why on earth are you using C strings, `strcpy` and `malloc` in C++ code ??? Save yourself a lot of grief and use `std::string`.

Comment: depreciated? apparently Microsoft hates it...

Comment: You're using `std::string` in your code already.  Why are you also using `char*` `calloc`, and `realloc`?  Is it because you believe you need to use them because a function wants a `char *` passed to it?

Comment: Why you are allocating the memory and then almost immediately reallocating it?

Comment: skip lines 2, 3 and replace line 7 with `char *ptr = (char*)alloc(top + eqn.size()+1);` But you should use `std::string` instead of c strings **unless you are using library saying otherwise**

Comment: The OP may be attempting to create a modifiable buffer from the `std::string` input.  If that's the case, there are better ways of doing it (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you're trying to achieve is to create a `modifiable` char buffer given a `std::string`, the better choice is to use `std::vector<char>` to create such a buffer.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//...
void foo(char *x)
{
   // do something to 'x'
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input the equation." << endl;
    string eqn;
    getline(cin, eqn);

    // construct vector with string
    std::vector<char> ptr(eqn.begin(), eqn.end());

    // add null terminator
    ptr.push_back(0);

    foo( &ptr[0] );
}
```

The above creates a modifiable, null-terminated C-string by utilizing the `std::vector` called `ptr`.  Note that there are no calls to `malloc`, `calloc`, etc.

Comment: For C++11 you have `foo( ptr.data() );`

Comment: Is there a way to not use `eqn` but directly input into the `ptr`. Like when we initialize a dynamic memory its gonna be `char *ptr;    ptr=new char[size]`. Here I don't know the `size`. and I want `ptr` to take up exactly the space required to store the `equation` and `\0`.

Comment: @an23lm My advice - keep the code in the answer.  The `getline` makes it virtually impossible to overrun a buffer since it uses `std::string`.  Any other input mechanism requires you to hard-code a size limit, or write some god-awful C++ code that mimics what `getline` does.

Comment: @an23lm - Also, the code above does exactly what you say you're trying to do.  There is no "wasted space".  The `std::string` is the same size as the input, and the `vector` is sized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` is deprecated because it's a common source of buffer overflow problems, that are generally fixed with `strncpy`.  Having said that, you are *much* better off using `std::string` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a duplicate of a string with `malloc`, you may simply use `strdup`:

```
char* ptr = strdup(eqn.c_str());
// ..
free(ptr);
```